# Android - Admob ads error. Thinks AdActivity isn't declared?

Tags: java, android, admob, android-activity

I am starting to pull my hair out over this:

I am trying to integrate ad's into my application (Android), but whenever I load my app, it displays:

```
You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges
```

But I do have it declared in the manifest!

I have tried using API 15, and API 8, but they both have the same outcome.

I am using the admob sdk 4.3.1.

Please can anybody help me at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is real working example:
Note: Ignore any warnings you may have in the manifest.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.zeem"
      android:versionCode="104"
      android:versionName="1.0.4">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.zeem.ZeemActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>**
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**default.properties**

```
target=android-13
```

Comment: Where is the default.properties file?